# How to disable/always allow assistive access on Mavericks?

Tags: keyboard, macos, services, accessibility

I've been using [this](https://gist.github.com/abbot/7121187) script (AppleScript) bound to a global hot key as an Automator Service to open new terminals using a global keyboard shortcut. After upgrade to OS X Mavericks when the corresponding service is triggered from *literally any* application, a new dialog box popus up saying that

> "(Application name)" would like to control this computer using accessibility features.

And of course script fails to execute triggered from any application which has not been explicitly given permission via System Preferences.

Is there some way to globally allow accessibility control to *any* application running on my computer in OS X Mavericks, as it used to be in previous OS X releases?

The example script above was not the only script I had on global shortcuts, and whitelisting *all* installed applications is extremely painful, especially considering that an app may be whitelisted only after a failed "control" attempt...

Answer (score 4):

I don't know any way to always allow access for assistive devices, but you can add multiple applications to the list in System Preferences by drag and drop:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Choose System Preferences from the Apple menu
2. Click on Security & Privacy
3. Click on the Privacy tab
4. Click on Accessibility in the list at the left
5. Click the lock icon to allow you to make changes (you'll be prompted for your password)
6. Check "(Application Name)"

I don't believe there is a way to set this setting globally. You need to do it for each application separately. I would love to be proven wrong...