# Applescript to turn on mirroring and set resolution to Scaled + 1440 x 900 when external display is connected

Tags: macos, display, applescript, resolution

When I connect an external display I need a script to automatically:
1. Check if external monitor is connected by detecting the "Attachment" tab exists.
2. Activate the "Attachment" Tab to focus.
3. Turn ON the mirroring only if it's off.
**Set Resolution as:**
4. "Optimize for" -> "Built-in Retina Display" (changing combobox).
5. "Scaled" (Radio button selection) .
6. "Select 1440 x 900". (option which is on the left of default).

I have a MacBook Pro 2017 running macOS 10.13, High Sierra, and a FullHD external display.
I prefer "scaled" down resolution of 1440 x 900 for most work instead of my system's default resolution of 1680 x 1050.

When sometime I connect the external display the MacBook Pro changes the resolution as per the external display and I then always need to resetup.

I have been trying to write up a applescript but not been able to get through. I dont want to use any extra apps like [SwitchResX](http://www.madrau.com) for this single case.

I have already tried the scripts at [Is it possible to change display resolution with a keyboard shortcut?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/263162/is-it-possible-to-change-display-resolution-with-a-keyboard-shortcut/) The script returns the error:

```
System Events got an error: Can’t get radio group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of window "Built-in Retina Display" of process "System Preferences". Invalid index.
```

Comment: Update: i have resoled the issue with the script by doing a minor change as below.    `click radio button 3 of radio group 1 of group 2 of tab group 1`

Comment: Great to see you got it resolved. :) Perhaps you'd like to add an answer your own question, as this will no doubt be useful to other users.

Comment: Sorry @Monomeeth i am still long way off to get all things working..still looking for a right way to detect external monitor is plugged.  Will surely share if i could get it all done.