# Toggle between two resolutions with a shortcut with Alfred

Tags: macos, applescript, shortcut, resolution, alfred

I wanna be able to toggle between these two resolutions with a single shortcut:

[image]

[image]

And I wanna have it set up in Alfred so that I may easily reuse across macs.

I believe I found most of the solution here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/263365/70489

However, it solves it in two separate actions/scripts. I want a single one that toggles between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
on alfred_script(q)
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of pane "com.apple.preference.displays"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" to tell window "Built-in Retina Display"
    set isScaled to value of radio button "Scaled" of tab group 1
    if isScaled = 0 then
        click radio button "Scaled" of tab group 1
        click radio button 4 of radio group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1
    else
        click radio button "Default for display" of tab group 1
    end if
end tell
quit application "System Preferences"
end alfred_script
```

[image]

Comment: **⇧⌘I** is a common shortcut already assigned to many _applications_. Does **Alfred**  usurp the _keyboard shortcut_ going to the _application_ that has focus that already has that _keyboard shortcut_ assigned and instead trigger your _script_?

Comment: @user3439894 Considering that the shortcut is always working for me, yes, I guess Alfred takes priority. But it's really up to you which shortcut you're gonna put in there.

Comment: RE: "But it's really up to you which shortcut you're gonna put in there." -- I'm well aware of that. The point I was trying to make is that commonly used _keyboard shortcuts_ such as **⇧⌘I** which is already set in, e.g., **Finder** and **Safari** just to name two, should, generally speaking, not be used like you have. Although as long as one is aware of the consequences, that's the important information.

Comment: @user3439894 you should not confuse 'commonly used' with presets.

Comment: RE: "you should not confuse 'commonly used' with presets." --  It is obviously clear that I was referring to _preset keyboard shortcuts_ and there is absolutely nothing wrong with my use of _commonly used_ in in this use case!