# a single keyboard shortcut that toggles between 2 resolutions on MacOS 12.6

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, display, applescript, automator

My own answer at https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/436069/53510 does not work for me now that my MacBook Pro has 12.6, and neither does this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/448556/53510

What do I need to update to get it to work again?

I want to easily toggle between "Default" and "More Space" shown here:

[image: screenshot]

**To have a single keyboard shortcut that toggles between 2 resolutions:**

1. Automator > File > New > [Quick Action](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/436073/53510) > Choose
2. Search for "Run AppleScript" and double-click the result.
3. Replace the default script code with what I provide below.
4. Try clicking the Run button a couple times to see if the toggling works.
5. Save as "toggle_display_resolution". (Later, if you ever want to edit it, you'll open `/Users/your_username/Library/Services/toggle_display_resolution.workflow` in Automator).
6. Close Automator.
7. System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services
8. Assign a keyboard shortcut to the new service that you created (which will probably be at the bottom of the list).

By the way, you may need to edit your "Security & Privacy" > Accessibility. See [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/436073/53510).

```
# https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/449891/53510
set monitor to 2
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.displays"
    delay 2
    tell application "System Events"
        tell window "Displays" of application process "System Preferences"
            click button "Display Settings…"
            delay 2
            click row monitor of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of sheet 1
            click radio button "Scaled" of radio group 1 of sheet 1
            tell sheet 1
                # ----------------------------------
                # from "try" to "end try" is the problem:
                try
                    set selected_button to button "Resolution4, Selected"
                    click button "Resolution1"
                on error
                    click button "Resolution4"
                end try
                # ----------------------------------
            end tell
            delay 0.5
            click button "Done" of sheet 1
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
# The next line is optional and could be commented out by prepending with a hash (#).
delay 2
quit application "System Preferences"
```

**I don't know how to specify the [Object Specifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-SW7) for buttons Resolution1 and Resolution4.**

I tried adding "in collection 1" because the Accessibility Inspector says that the container's type is "collection" (see screenshot below), but that didn't work.

[image: Accessibility Inspector screenshot]

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The command line utility `screenresolution` allows you to very easily change your display resolutions.

In **Terminal.app**, I installed [screenresolution](https://github.com/jhford/screenresolution) using [Homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/) with the command...

`brew install screenresolution`

After the successful installation of the `screenresolution` command line utility in Terminal, the commands...

`screenresolution list` lists all of the possible Display resolutions I can use.

`screenresolution get` shows me my current Display resolution.

So now if I want to change my Display resolution to 1440x900, it's as easy as using this one line of code...

`screenresolution set 1440x900x32@0`

So now instead of adding a Run AppleScript command to your workflow, add a Run Shell Script command instead.  You may need to add the full path like...

`/usr/local/bin/screenresolution set 1440x900x32@0`

---

**NOTE: The following is what I used for testing and troubleshooting.**

---

`screenresolution list` gave me the following results.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/lay4HVe.png]

From there I wanted to create a sorted list with only 1 available resolution per line and wrote that to a file called tmp.txt on my Desktop.  I used that file to loop through each item in that file to test changing my Display resolution to that item.

This following command what is what I used to create the tmp.txt on my Desktop...

`screenresolution list > ~/Desktop/tmp.txt ;grep -E '^ ' < ~/Desktop/tmp.txt |tr -cd "[:print:]" |tr ' ' '\n' |sort -n |uniq |sed '/^$/d' |pbcopy ;pbpaste > ~/Desktop/tmp.txt`

Now the contents of my tmp.txt looks like this...

[image]

This following command is what I used to loop through each line of the ~/Desktop/tmp.txt file to try changing my Display resolution to that item with a 3 second delay between each.

`while read line ;do screenresolution set "$line" ;sleep 3 ;done < ~/Desktop/tmp.txt`

These are the results.  Now I see which ones I can definitely use and which ones wont work.

[image]

*I purposely edited a few lines of the tmp.txt file so i could generate some errors.*

Comment: This looks so cool if it would work for me! But: https://github.com/jhford/screenresolution/issues/32#issuecomment-1310882526

Comment: Did you try the `screenresolution get` command first to see what you are currently set at?  I would do that first and then manually in System Settings.app and change your Display Res. to something else and then go back in Terminal and `screenresolution set` and insert the result from the `screenresolution get` result and see if that works.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'd tried.

Comment: I just noticed your update. Thanks. I tried your commands (including your loop), and none worked. All said `Error: mode ____.000000 not available on display 0` with lots of extra precision.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out:

**To have a single keyboard shortcut that toggles between 2 resolutions:**

1. Automator > File > New > [Quick Action](https://support.apple.com/guide/automator/use-quick-action-workflows-aut73234890a/mac) > Choose
2. Search for "Run AppleScript" and double-click the result.
3. Replace the default script code with what I provide below.
4. Try clicking the Run button a couple times to see if the toggling works.
5. Save as "toggle_display_resolution". (Later, if you ever want to edit it, you'll open `/Users/your_username/Library/Services/toggle_display_resolution.workflow` in Automator).
6. Close Automator.
7. System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services
8. Assign a keyboard shortcut to the new service that you created (which will probably be at the bottom of the list).

By the way, you may need to edit your "Security & Privacy" > Accessibility. See [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/436073/53510).

```
# https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/449891/53510
set monitor to 2
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.displays"
    delay 2
    tell application "System Events"
        tell window "Displays" of application process "System Preferences"
            click button "Display Settings…"
            delay 2
            click row monitor of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of sheet 1
            click radio button "Scaled" of radio group 1 of sheet 1
            tell sheet 1
                # ----------------------------------
                # from "try" to "end try" is the problem:
                try
                    set selected_button to button "Resolution4, Selected" of UI element 8
                    click button "Resolution1" of UI element 8
                on error
                    click button "Resolution4" of UI element 8
                end try
                # ----------------------------------
            end tell
            delay 0.5
            click button "Done" of sheet 1
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
# The next line is optional and could be commented out by prepending with a hash (#).
delay 2
quit application "System Preferences"
```

**How did I figure out the "of UI element 8" part?**

In Automator, I pressed the Record button, which recorded a Watch Me Do script of me manually editing Displays settings.

Then I dragged the steps from Watch Me Do into AppleScript and got the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I'm on MacOs 13.4.1 (c), [my previous answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/451552/53510) no longer works.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/417794/53510 led me to this solution, which seems to work well for me:

1. `brew tap jakehilborn/jakehilborn && brew install displayplacer`
2. `touch toggle_resolution.sh`
3. Make it executable: `chmod +x toggle_resolution.sh`
4. `displayplacer list` and find the ID of your display.
5. Edit its contents to be the code below, but using your display's ID and your desired resolutions.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/449891/53510

low_resolution="1920x1080"
high_resolution="3840x2160"

# Run displayplacer list and capture its output:
display_output=$(/usr/local/bin/displayplacer list)

# Find the first instance of "Resolution:" and extract the current resolution value:
current_resolution=$(echo "$display_output" | grep -m 1 "Resolution:" | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d '[:space:]')

echo "Current resolution: [$current_resolution]"
echo "high_resolution: [$high_resolution]"

if [ "$current_resolution" == "$high_resolution" ]; then
    echo "Decreasing resolution to $low_resolution:"
    /usr/local/bin/displayplacer "id:A5FA6A38-265A-E603-947C-278988C5CF85 res:$low_resolution hz:60 color_depth:8 scaling:on degree:0"
else
    echo "Increasing resolution to $high_resolution:"
    /usr/local/bin/displayplacer "id:A5FA6A38-265A-E603-947C-278988C5CF85 res:3840x2160 hz:60 color_depth:8 scaling:off degree:0"
fi
```

Create a keyboard shortcut to run that file:

1. Automator > New > Quick Action > Run Shell Script

```
cd /Users/yourName/code
./toggle_resolution.sh
```

2. At the top, ensure that your Quick Action receives "no input".

[image: Quick Action]

3. Save it as toggle_resolution
4. System Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts... > Services > text > toggle_resolution (set a shortcut, such as <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>ScrollLock</kbd>, which I prefer on my Win keyboard)

Comment: Now _this_ answer doesn't even work, now that my Mac is on Ventura 13.6.